# Android Address Bar and Bookmarklets

Tags: android, browser, bookmarklet, address-bar

I am currently working on a bookmarklet and have encountered something a little weird (and frustrating) with Android's Browser (seems to be device independent).

As you well know, when viewing a web page, as soon as you scroll down, the address bar in Browser hides. All well and good. However, it seems that if you invoke a bookmarklet, the address in the bar is replaced with a "javascript:" protocol address and the address bar **won't** auto-hide when you scroll.

No big deal, you'd think, but the content injected by my bookmarklet (which re-positions on scroll) is nicely covered by the address bar! I appreciate I could modify my code to just reposition slightly differently but there are reasons I'd like to avoid it at this stage.

Has anyone come across this particular issue before and are there are ways round it?

**UPDATE**: If it's worth anything, the "javascript:" protocol comment looks like a red herring. It seems to be because Browser thinks the page isn't loaded when my bookmarklet is invoked (little blue bar only goes a tenth of the way across and stops there). So, my question might be 'How do I accurately convince Browser than my page is loaded or kill the load?'

Comment: FWIW, I ended up having to re-adjust the position of my objects on Android. I just haven't been able to find a way around the address bar issue. But it's not even as simple as that. The number of pixels of adjustment depends on zoom level and orientation. It's ugly.

Comment: It's annoying. Reload the page won't even remove the bar, because it thinks "the page" is now the bookmarklet 'address'. Only going back/forward fixes it. I still haven't found a solution either. You?

Comment: @Rudie - No, we just left things as they were with the position adjustment in place for the default Android browser. But as we added more features we started to recommend using Chrome for compatibility reasons, and it didn't seem to have the same issues.